# I need to send two different email template after order purchase

Tags: php, magento, email, templates

I need to send the two different email template as per the product type or product attribute set.

I can't use the paid plugin. How can I write the code to change the setting? I have created the custom email template but in the sales email we can set only one template.

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the following

1. Rewrite `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` module to add your custom logic to `sendNewOrderEmail()`
2. You could disable order emails (see [Magento: send New Order Email only with cronjobs](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9936/magento-send-new-order-email-only-with-cronjobs)) then create an observer (eg `checkout_submit_all_after`) and do your own custom email sending logic in it.